# Как правильно «раздавать» код программистам?

Tags: git

Есть проект на джанго. Условно CRM. Уже в этом проекте много важного кода. Но я хочу подключить для каждого дополнительного функционала новых разработчиков. Какое самое оптимальное решение для "разбивки" проекта так, чтобы можно было "передавать" часть кода, а не весь проект?

Answer (score 1):

Ну типично - под необходимый, но ещё не существующий код в ООП-языках выделяют интерфейсы(либо заголовочные файлы в не ООП-языках), после чего собственно сторонним разработчикам и отдают код этих интерфейсов на их реализацию.

Часто дополнительно владельцы/лидеры проектов пишут модульные, либо поведенческие тесты к этим интерфейсом. Но это уже больше для уверенности в том, что сторонний разработчик корректно реализовал необходимый функционал.

Но это если код всего проекта действительно представляет прям-прям большую ценность, и утечка его - потенциальный крах всего бизнеса..

Сейчас чаще делают намного проще - дают доступ к репозиторию со всем кодом, ну и дальше - работают в отдельной ветке/репозитории, а потом сделанное сторонними разработчиками сливается в основной код. Ну и просто подписывают соглашение о неразглашении.

Comment: Подскажите, где можно прочитать про эти интерфейсы и что они из себя представляют?

Comment: имеются в виду interface как в Java или в C#

Answer (score 1):

Ищете в гугле информацию о том, что такое API и модульность кода. Если давать разработчикам копию проекта никак нельзя, то нужно дать им API для того, чтобы они могли делать расширения. Как вариант качественно задокументировать код и давать исполнителям документацию по тем частям, для которых он будет писать код.

Ещё советую почитать книги :

- Мифический человеко-месяц
- Совершенный код